# Need help in query development for the below scenario

Tags: db2

I have table structure as below

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
ID001  AB     1      R
ID001  CD     2      R
ID002  AB     1      R
ID002  CD     3      R
ID002  EF     4      R
ID003  AB     1      R
ID003  CD     2      R
ID003  PQ     4      R
ID004  PQ     1      R
ID004  RS     2      R
```

Input I am getting from the other resource is like this-:

Field2, field3 and field4 will be the input. Field2 and field3 will be sent in combination. Field 4 will be sent once.

```
Input 1-((AB,1,CD,2),R)
Input 2-((AB,1,CD,2,PQ,4),R) 

For this I should get field1 as the output.
For input 1, it should return ID001
For input 2, it should return ID003.
```

Can anybody help me out for this?

The whole requirement is to get `field1` from other fields.

Comment: Can you use the data `AB 1 R` to locate `ID001`- will that uniquely identify `IO001`?

Comment: No. some other ID(like ID003) can have the same data AB 1 R. We should match with the distinct count of field2,field3 for every field1 and also match the content of field2 and field3.

Comment: I have already found a solution for this using not in the query. But due to performance issues, I have been asked to changed the query. Please someone help on this

Comment: Maybe if you show us your solution to be transformed into a Query, we will be able to help you.     I cannot infer the formula form your specs.

Answer (score 0):

It works using the XML aggregation capabilities of DB2, and the input parameters as concatenated filter string:

```sql
select field1 from 
(
  select 
    field1,
    xmlcast(xmlgroup(field2 || field3 as a) as varchar(15)) as fields23,
    field4 
  from 
    your_table 
  group by 
    field1, field4
)
  where
    fields23 = 'AB1CD2' and field4 = 'R';
```

For the "Input 2" case use this filter:

```sql
...
  where
    fields23 = 'AB1CD2PQ4' and field4 = 'R';
```

Based on this blog entry: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/aggregating_strings42?lang=en